# (Php) BBcode same tag in tag interesting nested problem

Tags: php, html, nested, preg-replace, bbcode

This is my function.

```
class bbcode{
    var $bbcode_bb2html;
    function __construct($string){
            $this->bbcode_bb2html= $string;
    }
    function bbcode_parse_codes( ){
            $this->bbcode_bb2html = preg_replace("#\[code=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/code\]#si", "<pre data-snap-ignore=true class=language-\\1><code>\\2</code></pre>", $this->bbcode_bb2html);
            return $this->bbcode_bb2html;
    }
}
$content="[code=php]test message[/code]";
$bbcode = new bbcode($content);
echo $bbcode->bbcode_bb2html();
```

True result

```
<pre data-snap-ignore=true class=language-php><code>test message</code></pre>
```

But nested message not work. Sample;

```
$content="[code=php]test message [code=php]...[/code] bla bla bla[/code]";
$bbcode = new bbcode($content);
echo $bbcode->bbcode_bb2html();
```

False Result

`<pre data-snap-ignore=true class=language-php><code>test message [code=php]...</code></pre> bla bla bla[/code]`

Comment: function bbcode_bb2html(){
  if ( empty($this->bbcode_bb2html) ){
     return ( false );
  }   
        $this->bbcode_parse_codes( );
     return $this->bbcode_bb2html;
 }

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\[code=([^]]*)]([^[]*(?:\[(?!/code]|code=)[^[]*)*)\[/code]
```

and replace until no match is found. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ipIi7e/1). *Details*:

- `\[code=` - a `[code=` string
- `([^]]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `]` char
- `]` - a `]` char
- `([^[]*(?:\[(?!/code]|code=)[^[]*)*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than a `[` char, then zero or more occurrences of a `[` char that is not immediately followed with `/code]` or `code=` and then zero or more chars other than a `[` char
- `\[/code]` - `[/code]` string.

In [PHP code](https://3v4l.org/Ct9Ia), it will look like

```php
<?php

$text = '[code=php]test message [code=php]...[/code] bla bla bla[/code]';
$repl = '<pre data-snap-ignore=true class=language-$1><code>$2</code></pre>';
$count = 0;
do {
    $text = preg_replace('~\[code=([^]]*)]([^[]*(?:\[(?!/code]|code=)[^[]*)*)\[/code]~', $repl, $text, -1, $count);
} while ($count > 0);
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
<pre data-snap-ignore=true class=language-php><code>test message <pre data-snap-ignore=true class=language-php><code>...</code></pre> bla bla bla</code></pre>
```

To only get the surrounding tags you can use

```
(?s)\[code=([^]]*)]((?:(?!\[/?code\b).|(?R))*)\[/code]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ipIi7e/2). In PHP:

```php
preg_replace('~\[code=([^]]*)]((?:(?!\[/?code\b).|(?R))*)\[/code]~s', $repl, $text)
```

Comment: Your answer should be like this., <pre data-snap-ignore=true class=language-php><code>test message [code=php]...[/code] bla bla bla</code></pre>

Comment: @ulusanyazilim In the end you will still need to convert all these codes to html, won't you?

Comment: no, first and last tag only

Comment: @ulusanyazilim Then use regex recursion.

Comment: sample bbcode
[code]asd[code]asd[/code]asd[/code]

your code output 
<pre><code>asd<pre><code>asd</code></pre>asd</code></pre>

i want to be like this
<pre><code>asd[code]asd[/code]asd</code></pre>